# Why It is always need to use extends keyword before implements keyword?

Tags: java, inheritance

I was trying to extend from a class and implement an interface as well.Here is my code.

```
class A {

    public void print1() {
          System.out.println("Hello Class");
    }
}

interface B {

    public void print2();
}

class C extends A implements B {
    public void print2() {
        System.out.println("Interface");
    }
}
```

First I did is

```
class C implements B extends A  {
    public void print2() {
        System.out.println("Interface");
    }
}
```

And it leads to an error. 
It seems that `extends` keyword needs to come before `implements` . Why it is needed ? Any specific reasons  or is it just the way java is developed. ?

Comment: Because that is how the language is designed per the [Java Language Specification, sections 8.1.4 and 8.1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html).

Answer (score 1):

Because you can extend only from one class, but implement several interfaces. I think it's just a matter of good syntax style forced by the language's grammar. It seems like this question is duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538010/why-extends-precedes-implements-in-class-declaration) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is defined in the [JLS, section 8.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1):

```
NormalClassDeclaration:
{ClassModifier} class Identifier [TypeParameters] [Superclass] [Superinterfaces] ClassBody
```

Here you can clearly see that a superclass must be declared before any superinterface declarations.